# jquery jeditable save to database

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the following code to enable live edit with jeditable:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){


        var aDataSet = [
["klad1111.com","<img src='world/se.png' />","-","0","0","0%","0"],
["klad2222.com","<img src='world/dk.png' />","2012-12-05","1","3","300%","15"],
["klad33333.com","<img src='world/dk.png' />","-","0","0","0%","0"],
["klad6666.info","<img src='world/dk.png' />","-","0","0","0%","0"],
["klad44444.info","<img src='world/dk.png' />","-","0","0","0%","0"],
["klad5555.com","<img src='world/se.png' />","-","0","0","0%","0"],
    ];


    $('#dynamic').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' );
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aaData": aDataSet,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "Namn" },
            { "sTitle": "Land" },
            { "sTitle": "Uppdaterad" },
            { "sTitle": "Neutrala Posts", "sClass": "center" },
            { "sTitle": "Post / Client", "sClass": "center" },
            { "sTitle": "Ratio", "sClass": "center" },
            { "sTitle": "Total Posts", "sClass": "center" }                             
        ]
    } );



    /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
    $('td', oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable( 'editable_ajax.php', {
        "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
        },
        "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
            };
        },
        "height": "14px"
    } );

});

</script>
```

Live edit kind of works, when i click on a cell i get up a input box. But the save part is not working.. I am not sure how to update my database accordingly..

Any ideas?

Comment: Saving to the database happens in the php file. What have you done there?

Comment: install firebug or activate debugging console in IE or Chrome and see how the transaction worked, or add to your ajax call an error or send the error to console.log()